# Overloading constructor in generic scala class

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to overload a constructor in a generic scala class but it's not compiling.

Here's my code:

```
class V[T](m: Map[T,Double]) {
    def this(dt: Seq[Double]) = this(dt.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap)
}
```

And the error messages I get:

```
ERROR: called constructor's definition must precede calling constructor's definition : line 6

ERROR: overloaded method constructor V with alternatives:   
(dt: Seq[Double])V[T] <and>   (m: Map[T,Double])V[T]  cannot be applied to 
(scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Double]) : line 6
```

As far as I understand constructor overloading in scala, I think I'm following the proper syntax and the restriction that the call to `this` should precede everything else.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
def this(dt: Seq[Double]) = this(dt.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap)
```

- You're creating a new map `Map[Int,Double]`; `Int` being the type of the index created by `zipWithIndex`.
- If `T` were `Int`, then you can use the constructor `(m:Map[T,Double]`.
- However: T is not yet bound to a type since you're defining the class.  Nor will the type matching bind `T` to `Int` at this point.
- Therefore the type matching fails.

#### Solutions:

How to fix it depends on what you're trying to do.

- If it were the case that `T <: Int`, then bounding the type-param with `<: Int` could resolve your problem; however it seems a bit unlikely that `T` is a subclass of `Int`...
- If it is always true that `T : Int`, then drop the generic `T`.
- If `T` is to remain generic and unbounded then that leaves you with making a special case for when `T : Int`; senia's solution looks good for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with companion object:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class V[T](m: Map[T,Double])

object V{
  def apply(dt: Seq[Double]) = new V[Int](dt.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)(collection.breakOut))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class V
defined module V

scala> V(Seq(1.,2.,3.))
res0: V[Int] = V@1130e2ea
```